# How to parse the website using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, linkedin-api

I am new to web scraping and i want to get the html of the page.But when i run the program i get html empty and console show the javascript

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib

url = "https://linkedin.com/company/1005"

r = requests.get(url)
html_content = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'html.parser')
print (soup.prettify())
```

[image: error]

Comment: many pages use Javascript to read data from server and add elements to page. `BS` doesn't run JavaScript. You get the same HTML which get browser before it runs JavaScript. you can use Selenium to control browser and run JS. Or you can (manually) analyze page and find url which use JS to get data and then you can use requests to get this data.

Comment: So first i run selenium and then parse the data using beautifulsoup?

Comment: yes, run selenium which uses browse Chrome/Firefox (or headless browser like PhantomJS) to render page and then you can get all HTML. btw: You can even click button, fill form in this browse.

Comment: or analyze communication between browser and server (using DevTools in Chrome/Firefox) to find url used by browser to read more data and then you can use this url with requests. Sometimes you can get data as JSON which you easily convert to Python dictiorary.

Comment: i have already made the code by using **lxml**  and convert it into json form but now i want to change my apporach and use beautiful soup and em going nuts coz all i get is javascript

Comment: BS is not a problem - print `r.text` and you get the same HTML. I analyzed JS code and problem is because server tries to redirect you to login page. Probably you need more information in requests - like `user-agent` header, etc. Or you have to use requests to login on server first. You can use Devtools in Chrome/Firefox to see what data/headers sends browser when it connects to your url.

Answer (score 17):

Problem is not `BeautifulSoup` but server which needs more information in requests to give you access to this page. Now it sends JavaScript code which redirects you to login page.

You need `User-Agent` header to get this page.

You can use http://httpbin.org/get to see `User-Agent` in your browser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = "https://linkedin.com/company/1005"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Small correction: `import requests` instead of `import request`