# Two almost identical codes, one works but the other doesn't

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I dont know why the first code works but second doesnt. After "adidas" code i gets answers "connection aborted, OSError 10054". I'v heard something about API on websites, to be honest i dont know what is it but i fell thats related :D

IT WORKS:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

odpowiedz = requests.get("https://www.nike.com/pl/w?q=react%20270&vst=react%20270")
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')
```

IT DOESN'T WORK:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

odpowiedz = requests.get("https://www.adidas.pl/search?q=ultraboost")
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: There seems to be a dns resolution issue or something? Requests can't get it, but Firefox and Chrome can.

Comment: Note some web pages might denied access based on User Agent

Comment: Is there ani tip how to avoid the denied access?

Comment: Have a look through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255128/how-to-parse-the-website-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) instead of requests to get the page source

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.adidas.pl/search?q=ultraboost")
source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
```

If you want to exit chrome after you got the page source use driver.quit()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.adidas.pl/search?q=ultraboost")
source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
```

If you don't want the chrome tab to appear

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.adidas.pl/search?q=ultraboost")
source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

*Daweo* is right, the Adidas server checks the `User-Agent` header.

This works for me:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0",
           #"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
           #"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           }

odpowiedz = requests.get("https://www.adidas.pl/search?q=ultraboost", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(odpowiedz.text, 'html.parser')
```

It even accepts `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaadaaaMozilla"`.

For Adidas.com, if you don't have an acceptable `User-Agent`, it returns a page explaining why:

> During high-traffic product releases we have extra security in place to prevent bots entering our site. We do this to protect customers and to give everyone a fair chance of getting the sneakers. Something in your setup must have triggered our security system, so we cannot allow you onto the site.